# Random pictures from start slider js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a simple image slider and im pretty much new to JS.
This is HTML of slider.

```
<a class="thumb-box scroll-to-section" href="#people">
  <img src="someimg" class="peoples-img" style="display: none;">
  <img src="someimg2" class="peoples-img" style="display: none;">
  <img src="someimg3" class="peoples-img" style="display: none;">
  <img src="someimg4" class="peoples-img" style="display: none;">                
  <h3 class="thumb-box__title">People</h3>
</a>
```

and here is the JS code

var myIndex = 0;
    carousel();

```
function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("peoples-img");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

slider works fine img by img, but i want to make slider to shuffle images. And everytime I reload page to open different image, any suggestion?

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("peoples-img");
var randomIndex = new Array();

function shuffle() {
    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++){
        randomIndex.push(i);
    }

    //http://stackoverflow.com/a/18650169/1582080
    randomIndex.sort(function() {
        return .5-Math.random();
    });
}

function carousel() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
    x[randomIndex[myIndex-1]].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}

var myIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*x.length);
shuffle();
carousel();
```

Comment: Yeah its good thanks a lot :) but every time i reload it starts from different image. But is there any way to make it shuffle al the time because when images start going trough the slide they go in order, i want them to shuffle all the time

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range) you can find instructions on how to generate a random number. Use this number to access a random element in your array. This way each time you will show a random image.